# Creating a subplot below a plot with an inset graph in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, zooming, graphing, subplot

I currently have the graph attached. I want a separate graph underneath this one showing the difference between the two lines to visually show the functional approach to error analysis.

How do I add a subplot below this graph with a space and new axes without effecting the size and shape of my current graph.[image]

My current code is:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.plot(x, y1, label = 'label1')
plt.plot(x, y2, label = 'label2')
plt.plot(x, y3, label = 'label2')

plt.xlabel(u'Redshift (z)', fontname = 'Times New Roman', size = 15)
plt.ylabel(u'Look-back Time (yrs)', fontname = 'Times New Roman', size = 15)

legend = plt.legend(loc='lower right', shadow=True, fontsize='large')
axins = zoomed_inset_axes(ax, 4.5, loc=10)

axins.plot(x, y1, label = 'label1')
axins.plot(x, y2, label = 'label2')
axins.plot(x, y3, label = 'label2')

x1, x2, y1, y2 = 2, 2.5, 1.25*10**10, 1.3*10**10

axins.set_xlim(x1, x2)
axins.set_ylim(y1, y2)

mark_inset(ax, axins, loc1=1, loc2=3, fc="none", ec="0.5")

plt.show()
```

When I try to add a subplot below I used this code:

```
plt.subplot(212)
plt.plot(yaxis, difference(y2, y3))
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom = 0.1, hspace=5)
```

It just creates a smaller plot in a new figure. Where as I want one to be underneath the other.

Comment: Do you want two subplots to appear in the same figure sharing the same x axis? Or you could just set the position of the two figures that you create with the code above so that they appear one above the other.

Comment: Yeah literally, I am just not sure how to put one figure about the other without my inset not working.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is correct, but you need to add a new subplot before calling for plt.show(). This is because after that call, the instance of the figure is killed after you close it.

In general, you may want to call directly the method add_subplot() of your figure instance (in your case fig.add_subplot()) because then you make sure it's added to the desired object.