# Easy way to plot second plot as section of first plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a time-series plot of data in which I want to examine a section in more detail. Kind of like [this](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/dpCAhtnh458/maxresdefault.jpg), but with the second plot being below the first, and instead of the box bounding the section of data, bounding the x-axis labels instead.

Is there a simple way to go about this or am I going to have to write this from scratch?

EDIT: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35710402/creating-a-subplot-below-a-plot-with-an-inset-graph-in-python) past question seems to be after the same thing, but was never solved.

Comment: I'd say you have to do it yourself. But that shouldn't be too hard... Just create 2 subplots with different xlims...