# Plot zoomed inset plot of a plot with square and lines

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a zoomed inset plot with lines and box showing which part of the plot is zoomed.
Is this possible in R?
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35710402/creating-a-subplot-below-a-plot-with-an-inset-graph-in-python) is an example of what I would like to do done in Python.
Some sample code:

```
    p <-
  qplot(1:10, 1:10)
g <-
  p +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(8, 10), xlim = c(8, 10)) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank())
p +
  annotation_custom(
    grob = ggplotGrob(g),
    xmin = 7,
    xmax = 10,
    ymin = 1,
    ymax = 5
  )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe the following code does what the question asks for. Or, at least, it gives an idea of how to solve the problem.

The region zoomed in is displayed with `geom_path` drawing a rectangle and the connecting lines with `geom_line`. To do this two new data sets giving the square's vertices and the lines' end points are created.

```
polydata <- data.frame(x = c(7.9, 10.1, 10.1, 7.9, 7.9),
                       y = c(7.9, 7.9, 10.1, 10.1, 7.9))
linedata <- data.frame(x = c(7.9, 7, 10.1, 10),
                       y = c(7.9, 5, 7.9, 5),
                       id = c("a", "a", "b", "b"))
p +
  geom_path(data = polydata, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_line(data = linedata, aes(x, y, group = id),
            linetype = "solid") +
  annotation_custom(
    grob = ggplotGrob(g),
    xmin = 7,
    xmax = 10,
    ymin = 1,
    ymax = 5
  )
```

[image]

If the inset is redefined with `plot.background` taking custom values, the result can be made prettier.

```
g <-
  p +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(8, 10), xlim = c(8, 10)) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        plot.background = element_rect(colour = "black", fill = NA, size = 1))
```

[image]